# object not responding to Underscore shuffle

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm working on a backbone project with underscore (1.3.0). Underscore has a shuffle method that shuffles

create a collection

```
countries = new Countries
child
```

check length

```
countries.length
0
```

fetch the data (using an underscore method, fetch)

```
 countries.fetch();
    Object
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:3000/countries". jquery.js:8215
```

Now it has a length of four

```
  countries.length
    4
```

try to return a randomly shuffled array
    countries.shuffle();
    TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'shuffle'

shuffle otherwise works in my environment

```
   _.shuffle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
[2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 3]
```

I watched Ryan Bates backbone railscast, and he essentially does the same thing but his works. One difference, though, was when he created his Collection object, it had a different return value

```
entries = new Raffler.Collections.Entries()
entries #return value
```

However, when I create a collection, it returns 'child'

```
 countries = new Countries
    child
```

But I don't see that making a difference because I'm still able to call countries.fetch(); which is an underscore method.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be using an old version of Backbone, or a version of underscore that's not compatible with your version of Backbone.

The first version of Backbone to include the `Collection.shuffle` method was 0.9.0. The documentation in those days did not specify the minimum version for underscore, but for Backbone 0.9.1 the minimum was `> 1.3.1`. For the current Backbone release (0.9.9) it's `> 1.4.3`.

Also, `fetch` is not an underscore method.

Comment: must have been the problem, as it's now fixed with a reinstall